# Kubernetes nginx ingress-controller on Azure not reachable

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I am very new to Azure, Kubernetes, even Docker itself, and playing with the system to learn and evaluate for a possible deployment later. I have so far dockerized my services and successfully deployed them and made the web frontend publicly visible using a service with type: LoadBalancer.

Now I would like to add TLS termination and have learned that for that I am supposed to configure an ingress controller with the most commonly mentioned one being nginx-ingress-controller.

Strictly monkeying examples and then afterwards trying to read up on the docs I have arrived at a setup that looks interesting but does not work. Maybe some kind soul can point out my mistakes and/or give me pointers on how to debug this and where to read more about it.

I have kubectl apply'd the following file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend-deployment
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: default-http-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - name: default-http-backend
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80  
  selector:
    app: default-http-backend
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller-conf
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  # enable-vts-status: 'true'
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller-deployment
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress-controller
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.13
          name: nginx-ingress-controller
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              hostPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
              hostPort: 443
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller-conf
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress-controller
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: 
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: default-http-backend-service
              servicePort: 80
```

This gave me two pods:

```
c:\Projects\Release-Management\Azure>kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
<some lines removed>
kube-system   default-http-backend-deployment-3108185104-68xnk       1/1       Running   0          39m
<some lines removed>
kube-system   nginx-ingress-controller-deployment-4106313651-v7p03   1/1       Running   0          24s
```

Also two new services. Note that I have also configured the default-http-backend-service with type: LoadBalancer, this is for debugging only. I have included my web-frontend which is called webcms:

```
c:\Projects\Release-Management\Azure>kubectl get services --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                               CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
<some lines removed>
default       webcms                             10.0.105.59    13.94.250.173   80:31400/TCP                 23h
<some lines removed>
kube-system   default-http-backend-service       10.0.106.233   13.80.68.38     80:31639/TCP                 41m
kube-system   nginx-ingress-controller-service   10.0.33.80     13.95.30.39     443:31444/TCP,80:31452/TCP   37m
```

And finally an ingress:

```
c:\Projects\Release-Management\Azure>kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME            HOSTS     ADDRESS      PORTS     AGE
kube-system   nginx-ingress   *         10.240.0.5   80        39m
```

No errors that I can immediately detect. I then went to the Azure Dashboard and looked at the loadbalancer and its rules and that looks good to my (seriously untrained) eye. I did not touch these, the loadbalancer and the rules were created by the system. There is a screenshot here:

https://qvwx.de/tmp/azure-loadbalancer.png

But unfortunately it does not work. I can curl my webcms-service:

```
c:\Projects\Release-Management\Azure>curl -v http://13.94.250.173
* Rebuilt URL to: http://13.94.250.173/
*   Trying 13.94.250.173...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 13.94.250.173 (13.94.250.173) port 80 (#0)
<more lines removed, success>
```

But neither default-http-backend nor the ingress work:

```
c:\Projects\Release-Management\Azure>curl -v http://13.80.68.38
* Rebuilt URL to: http://13.80.68.38/
*   Trying 13.80.68.38...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 13.80.68.38 port 80 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to 13.80.68.38 port 80: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 13.80.68.38 port 80: Timed out
```

(ingress gives the same with a different IP)

If you read this far: Thank you for your time and I would appreciate any hints.

Marian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of a trivial thing, but it'll save you some $$$: the `default-http-backend` is not designed to be outside facing, and thus should not have `type: LoadBalancer` -- it is [merely designed to 404](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/nginx-0.9.0-beta.13/controllers/nginx/examples/default-backend.yaml#L19) so the Ingress controller can universally `/dev/null` traffic for Pod-less Services.

---

Moving slightly up the triviality ladder, and for extreme clarity: I do not think what you have is *wrong* but I did want to offer you something to decide if you want to change. Typically the contract for a Pod's container is to give an ideally natural-language name to the port ("http", "https", "prometheus", whatever) that maps into the port of underlying image. And then, set `targetPort:` in the Service to that *name* and not the *number* which offers the container the ability to move the port number without breaking the Service-to-Pod contract. [The nginx-ingress Deployment's container:ports:](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blame/nginx-0.9.0-beta.13/docs/troubleshooting.md#L269-L274) agrees with me on this one.

---

Now, let's get into the parts that may be contributing to your system not behaving as you wish.

I can't prove it right now, but the presence of [containers:hostPort:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#containerport-v1-core) is suspicious without [hostNetwork: true](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#container-v1-core). I'm genuinely surprised `kubectl` didn't whine, because those config combinations are a little weird.

I guess the troubleshooting step would be to get on the `Node` (that is, something within the cluster which is not a Pod -- you could do it with a separate VM within the same subnet as your `Node`, too, if you wish) and then curl to port 31452 of the `Node` upon which the `nginx-ingress-controller` Pod is running.

`kubectl get nodes` will list all available `Node`s, and

`kubectl get -o json pod nginx-ingress-controller-deployment-4106313651-v7p03 | jq -r '.items[0].status.hostIP'` should produce the specific VM's IP address, if you don't already know it. Err, I just realized from your prompt you likely don't have `jq` -- but I don't know PowerShell well enough to know its JSON-querying syntax.

Then, from any `Node`: `curl -v http://${that_host_IP_value}:31452` and see what materializes. It may be something, or it may be the same "wha?!" that the LoadBalancer is giving you.

---

As for the Ingress resource specifically, again default-http-backend is not supposed to have an Ingress resource -- I don't know if it hurts anything because I've never tried it, but I'd also bet $1 it is not *helping* your situation, either.

Since you already have a known working `Service` with `default:webcms`, I would recommend creating an Ingress resource in the `default` namespace with pretty much exactly what your current Ingress resource is, but pointed at `webcms` instead of `default-http-backend`. That way your Ingress controller will actually have something to target which isn't the default backend.

If you haven't already seen it, [adding --v=2](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/nginx-0.9.0-beta.13/controllers/nginx#debug--troubleshooting) will cause the Pod to emit the actual diff of its nginx config change, which can be **unbelievably** helpful in tracking down config misunderstandings

---

I'm so sorry that you're having to do battle with Azure, Ingress controllers, and rough-around-the-edges documentation for your first contact with Kubernetes. It really is amazing when you get all the things set up correctly, but it is a pretty complex piece of machinery, for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it has been most welcome and helped me a lot. I made progress and got the thing to work very nicely.

For the record I think my problem was not so much in the configuration shown, but with DNS resolution, I was just generally confused. A condition that has gotten a lot better recently. 

There is no need to be sorry for me, I find the documentation from core-Kubernetes, the nginx ingress controller and even Microsoft for the Azure-integration quite helpful. 

There's just a lot to take in.

Thanks again for the very helpful answer.